# How to track if employees are late which has more than one work schedules or shifts?

Tags: mysql

I have designed a MySQL database for an employee monitoring system, it was working perfectly well until I was asked to put a new work schedule for some of the employees.

The new schedule was what they called a broken schedule because an employee would have different shifts in one day, for example, an employee could be given a work schedule for a given day starting from 7:00AM-11:00AM and then continues at 3:00PM-7:00PM...

The problem I encountered now is, I am confused on how to keep track if the employees are late of not now that some employees have two or more work schedules...

Could anyone help me pls?

**addendum:**

for more clarity, lets say we have employee A. employee A for example has the following work schedule for a given day - 5 days in a week.
        7:00AM-11:00AM - shift 1
        3:00PM-7:00PM  - shift 2
        9:00PM-11:30PM - shift 3

then, lets say employee A logged in at these different scenarios:
scenario #1: logged in at 7:10AM
scenario #2: logged in at 2:30PM

how do I check that employee A's log info at scenario #1 is not referencing shift2 or shift3?
likewise, how do I check if employee A's log info at scenario #2 would only reference shift2 only and would not make him/her late at his/her schedule at shift #1 or too early at shift #3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules I would have applied to determine the validity of the scenarios seems pretty straightforward:

When a clock-in occurs *between* the start and end times of "any" assigned shift, that's a late clock-in for the shift with the start and end times that the clock-in occurs "between" (scenario 1)...

Conversely, when the clock-in is *prior* to the start time of an assigned shift but also *after* the end time of another shift (or, to state this another way, it occurs "not between" the start and end of any other assigned shift), that's an early clock-in (scenario 2) for the next shift to start after the clock-in event.

It seems that both pieces can be combined together:

(pseudocode)

SELECT sch.start_time, sch.stop_time from employee JOIN employee_schedule JOIN schedule sch WHERE sch.stop_time > clock_in_time ORDER BY stop_time LIMIT 1;

I would suggest that this query should *always* return the schedule to which the clock-in timestamp applies.  It's "the first shift that ended after you clocked in."

If the start_time of the shift is earlier than the clock_in_time, then you're late... if it's later than the clock_in_time, then you're early.

Comment: awesome!!! works perfect, thank you so much sir

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely cannot add a column to your schedule or employee to reference the shift in question explicitly, you could make assumptions regarding the length of time between a log in and a shift start to determine this.

Comment: You mean linking them together?...My current table relationship for employee and their schedule uses 3 tables, 
the 'employee' table containing employee info, 
the 'schedule' table containing schedule info,
and a junction table named 'employee_schedule' for linking the employee and a schedule.
inside the emplyee_schedule table, an employee could be linked into several schedules or shifts...

Comment: Also, I already tried doing your second suggestion by making assumptions regarding the length of time between a log in and a shift start...and it kinda brings me back to my previous problem like in my posted question above...